# How do I deallocate a Linux RAMDISK, e.g. /dev/ram0?

Tags: linux, memory, ramdisk

I've been playing with Linux RAMDISKs, as in the block device `/dev/ram0`. I understand that when I first start writing to one of these devices some RAM is allocated to it.

How do I free the memory used by, say, `/dev/ram0`? Put another way: how do I indicate to the Linux kernel that I'm done and it can reclaim whatever resources are held by `/dev/ram0`?

Comment: Did you mount the ram disk to something like /mnt/ramdisk?

Comment: I used `mkfs /dev/ram0` and then mounted it, did some experiments (testing how my app copes with out of disk-space conditions) and unmounted it. But that doesn't free the memory that backs /dev/ram0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you format the ramdisk something along the lines of

```
mke2fs -m 0 /dev/ram0
```

The ramdisks themselves don't actually occupy any memory space.

If you do format and mount a ramdisk however, the only way that I remember doing is by using [freeramdisk](http://man.cx/freeramdisk%288%29) but that was a long long time ago.

Some other resources you might want to check out:

http://e2enetworks.com/2008/10/25/linux-in-memory-filesystems-tmpfs-vs-ramdisk/

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html

http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: Thanks `freeramdisk` does the trick. Verified by experiment while watching the output from `free`.

Comment: Please update your question. There are dead links.

Comment: What makes you think "*The ramdisks themselves don't actually occupy any memory space.*"? Where is data stored in your opinion?

Comment: This answer is a very good example why you should *write* an answer instead of referring to other sources: All three links given as "other resources" are dead links now, so the information is basically lost.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254254/59928) it doesn't work. Also, the other answer here mentions that all `freeramdisk` does is it calls `BLKFLSBUF` ioctl, which is exactly the same as what `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0` does, and the blockdev does not remove a `ram0` for me.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/ram0 and other are implemented by brd linux kernel module: Source - http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/block/brd.c, documentation of `modprobe brd`: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7012396.

Try to unload (rmmod) the module with `rmmod brd`, this is the only way to call `brd_del_one` function and delete ramdisk.

Freeram is part of loadlin package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/loadlin/1.6f-5 and implemented as opening device to read/write and doing BLKFLSBUF ioctl

```
  char rname[256]="/dev/ram";
  char b[256];
  int f;
  f=open(rname,O_RDWR))
  ioctl(f,BLKFLSBUF);
```

which is defined in https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/fs.h as

```
   #define BLKFLSBUF  _IO(0x12,97)  /* flush buffer cache */
```

Comment: Well, doesn't `rmmod brd` remove *all* AM disks? I know it wasn't asked for exactly, but how would you remove a single RAM disk (in case you created multiple)?

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Consider what exactly was already developed by your whole body

Red-colored Cap produces of sixteen ramdisks automatically, although there're not necessarily "active" or making use of almost any RAM. It listings products ram0 : ram 19, however solely ram0 : ram15 are usually usable automatically. To check on these block products out there, utilize the using get:

```
[root]# ls -l /dev/ram*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root four Jun 12 00: thirty-one /dev/ram -> ram1
```

Step 2: Improve ramdisk size

Ramdisk size can be controlled by way of command-line solution which is passed on the kernel in the course of trunk. Since GRUB could be the default bootloader intended for Red-colored Cap 9, I'll transform `/etc/grub.conf` while using brand new kernel solution. The actual kernel solution intended for ramdisk size can be: `ramdisk_size=xxxxx`, where xxxxx could be the size indicated with 1024-byte hindrances. Can do for you I'll complement `/etc/grub.conf` for you to configure of sixteen MB ramdisks

Step 3: Data format the particular ramdisk

There' no requirement for you to file format the particular ramdisk as a journaling file process, therefore most of us only will utilize the common ext2 file process. When i solely desire to use one particular ramdisk, so i is only going to file format `/dev/ram0`:

Step: Make a attach place along with attach the particular ramdisk

Today you have formatted the particular ramdisk, you need to make a attach place for doing this. Then you can definitely attach your current ramdisk along with work with it. Many of us will use the particular service `/mnt/rd` because of this operations.

Activity 5: Make use of the ramdisk

Since it has been designed, you can easlily replicate, shift, get rid of, revise, along with quantity data files round the ramdisk as provided that these people wound up with the actual physical hard drive partiton. This is actually the fantastic position intended for a peek at decrypted GPG or possibly OpenSSL data files, in addition to a fantastic position for just a crank out data files which is to be encrypted. Right after your own host is definitely run lower, a lot of record linked with data files designed round the ramdisk have left.

In order to unmount this ramdisk, merely enter your next:

```
[root]# umount -v /mnt/rd
/dev/ram0 umounted.
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question though - unmounting a ramdisk does *not* deallocate the memory: if you remount it the data is still where you left it. As per the accepted answer, `freeramdisk` does the trick.